# String replacement loop using Python dictionary

Tags: python

Can someone suggest the best way to do an iterative string replacement from a dictionary?

I'm going to go down a column of addresses, which look like:

```
Address1=" 122 S 102 ct,"
```

I have my conversion logic as:

```
CT=['ct','ct,','ct.','court']
DR=['drive,','drive.','drive','driv','dr,','dr.','dr']
dictionary={"CT":CT, "DR":DR}
```

How should I search for all dictionary values within `Address1` and replace them with the corresponding key?

The goal is for `" 122 S 102 ct,"` to become `" 122 S 102 CT"`, etc.

I can't quite get the syntax to replace with the corresponding key.

Comment: Did you try anything? Do you have any code to show?

Comment: Have you tried looking at [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try?:

```
Splits = Address1.split("")
for i in Splits:
    if i in CT:
        i = 'CT'
    if i in DR:
        i = 'DR'

print(" ".join(Splits))  # " " will keep the spacing between words
```

Comment: May be also replace punctuation ".,:", with space

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sketch of a solution.

### With Original Approach

You should use a dictionary from string to list of string, e.g.

```
conversions = {
    'CT': [ 'ct', 'ct,' 'ct.', 'court' ],
    'DR': [ 'drive', 'drive.', 'driv', 'dr', 'dr.' ]
}
```

Now, you can step through each word in the input, and replace it:

```
def get_transformed_address(input):
    result = ''
    for word in input.split(' ')
        result += ' ' + maybe_convert(word)

    return result
```

Where `maybe_convert()` is:

```
def maybe_convert(phrase):
    for canonical, representations in conversions.items():
        if representations.contains(phrase):
            return canonical

    # default is pass-through of input
    return phrase
```

### With Regex

Probably a cleaner solution is to just use a map of replacement regexes on the input. e.g.

```
conversions = {
    '/court_pattern_here/': 'CT',
    '/drive_pattern_here/': 'DR'
}
```

and then:

```
for regex, replacement in conversions.items():
    input = input.replace(regex, replacement)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can prebuild inverse dictionary with an activestate dictionary inversion snippet

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/415100-invert-a-dictionary-where-values-are-lists-one-lin/

```
def invert(d):
   return dict( (v,k) for k in d for v in d[k] )
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample that might help. Your mileage may vary.

```
CT=['ct','ct,','ct.','court']
DR=['drive,','drive.','drive','driv','dr,','dr.','dr']
dictionary={"CT":CT, "DR":DR}
address1 =' 122 S 102 ct,'
```

We start by looking at each key and matching value (i.e. your list of elements).
We then iterate over each element in the value and check to see if the element is present. If yes... we then use the replacement method to replace the offending element with the key from the dictionary.

```
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    for element in value:
        if element in address1:
            address_new = address1.replace(element, key)
print(address_new)
```

Comment: Original will replace  driftwood str. , you might need break into words see split-join technique. if element in address1: might be not useful.

Comment: Courtland street would become ctland street http://www.openstreetmap.org/way/10167126

Answer (score 1):

```
from string import punctuation

def transform_input(column):
  words = column.rstrip(punctuation).split()
  for key, values in conversions.items():
      for ind, word in enumerate(words):
          if word in values:
            words[ind] = key
  return ' '.join(words)


Address1=" 122 S 102 ct,"

conversions = {
    'CT': [ 'ct', 'ct,' 'ct.', 'court' ],
    'DR': [ 'drive', 'drive.', 'driv', 'dr', 'dr.' ]
}

print(transform_input(Address1)) # 122 S 102 CT
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone for the help. Here is what I ended up with.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import re 

    inputinfo="C:\\path"
    data=pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel(inputinfo,parse_cols ="A",converters={"A":str}))

    TRL=['trl']
    WAY=['wy']                                                                 #do before HWY
    HWY=['hwy','hy']
    PATH=['path','pth']
    LN=['lane','ln.','ln']
    AVE=['avenue','ave.','av']
    CIR=['circle','circ.','cir']
    TER=['terrace','terace','te']
    CT=['ct','ct,','ct.','court']
    PL=['place','plc','pl.','pl']
    CSWY=['causeway','cswy','csw']
    PKWY=['parkway','pkway','pkwy','prkw']
    DR=['drive,','drive.','drive','driv','dr,','dr.','dr']
    PSGE=['passageway','passage','pasage','pass.','pass','pas']
    BLVD=['boulevard','boulevar','blvd.','blv.','blvb','blvd','boul','bvld','bl.','blv','bl']

    regex=r'(\d)(th)|(\d)(nd)|(3)(rd)|(1)(st)'
    Lambda= lambda m: m.group(1) if m.group(1) else m.group(3) if m.group(3) else m.group(5) if m.group(5)else m.group(7) if m.group(7) else ''
# the above takes care of situations like "123 153*rd* st"

    for row in range(0,data.shape[0]):
            String = re.sub(regex,Lambda,str(data.loc[row,"Street Name"]))
            Splits = String.split(" ")
            print (str(row)+" of "+str(data.shape[0]))
            for i in Splits:
                    ind=Splits.index(i)
                    if i in AVE:
                            Splits[ind]="AVE"
                    if i in TRL:
                            Splits[ind]="TRL"
                    if i in WAY:
                            Splits[ind]="WAY"
                    if i in HWY:
                            Splits[ind]="HWY"
                    if i in PATH:
                            Splits[ind]="PATH"
                    if i in TER:
                            Splits[ind]="TER"
                    if i in LN:
                            Splits[ind]="LN"
                    if i in CIR:
                            Splits[ind]="CIR"
                    if i in CT:
                            Splits[ind]="CT"
                    if i in PL:
                            Splits[ind]="PL"
                    if i in CSWY:
                            Splits[ind]="CSWY"
                    if i in PKWY:
                            Splits[ind]="PKWY"
                    if i in DR:
                            Splits[ind]="DR"
                    if i in PSGE:
                            Splits[ind]="PSGE"
                    if i in BLVD:
                            Splits[ind]="BLVD"  
            data.loc[row,"Street Name Modified"]=(" ".join(Splits))

    data.to_csv("C:\\path\\StreetnameSample_output.csv",encoding='utf-8')
```